# PHP: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded, continue looping

Tags: php

I'm writing a a php script where i do a loop and inside the loop there is a particular function processing information, as illustrated here.

```
while (some condition){
    // some code
    processInformation();
    // Some more code
}
```

Well it turns out that midway, inside processInformation(), I encountered the error Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded. Using set_time_limit(0), would not help in my situation because processInformation() might take forever. I don't want an error to completely break my program, so is there anyway i can catch an exception or tell php to "continue" the loop if processInformation() takes too long?

Comment: Have the `processInformation();` function keep track of the time it's taken, and if it's close to the max execution time, return with an error condition (or throw an Exception within the function).

Comment: What does `processInformation` do that takes so long?

Comment: php can do a lot in 30 seconds.  It usually means logic in the function is not setting the some condition variable to break out of the loop.

Comment: @nickb, good idea, but how do you suggest keeping tracking of the time?

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the value of maximum execution time from 30 seconds to any value. For example: if you want to set the limit of maximum execution time of 3 minutes (instead of 30 seconds), then you can set as:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 180); //maximum execution time of 3 minutes
```

This way, you can set the time based on your need.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno how to catch the exception but you could use a simple time calculation to escape after say 60 secs. ()

$x=time();
while (some condition){

```
    processInformation();

    if ($x + 60) < time() 
    break;

}
```